# This or that click using UIButton in Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton

I am using single button to display login fields. If we click once, login view move left side, and sign up view will display, then, if we click again, sign up view will move right side, login view will display. My coding is below. But Animation is not working. Kindly guide me.

```
var bottom_click : Bool = true

@IBAction func not_member_button(sender: UIButton) {

    if(bottom_click == false) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.login_view.frame = CGRectMake(16, 150, 288, 187)
            self.crea_acc_view.frame = CGRectMake(370, 150, 288, 245)
            }, completion: { finished in

                //println("Basket doors opened!")
        })
        sender.titleLabel?.text = "Not a member? Sign Up" //Its not working. If we delete this, animation is working
        bottom_click = true
    }
    else {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.login_view.frame = CGRectMake(-500, 150, 288, 187)
            self.crea_acc_view.frame = CGRectMake(16, 150, 288, 245)
            }, completion: { finished in

                //println("Basket doors opened!")
        })
        sender.titleLabel?.text = "Already member? Login" // Its is not working. If we delete this, animation is working
        bottom_click = false
    }

}
```

Comment: what is not working? what is wrong with the animation that's happening?

Comment: hi.. I have edited again. Animation also not working, and then, Sender.titleLabel?.text also not working?

Comment: please add more details about what isn't working, deos the function get called but the conditions aren't met, or the function isn't called at all?

Comment: are you using auto layout? then read this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25773952/animation-blocks-resets-to-original-position-after-updating-text

Comment: Hi..! function is called. Condition is working perfectly. Animations are not working.

Comment: then it could be the autoLayout issue as @rakeshbs mentioned

Comment: Yes! I read. But, if we omit that sender.title label line, animation is working perfectly. I couldn't change button title.

Comment: Is there any way to solve?? I need auto layout also for constraints.

Comment: Have you tried putting sender.titleLabel?.text before animation block ?