# animation: stop reset position of an element (swift)

Tags: swift, animation

I'm trying animations and I'm facing a big problem: when my animation finished and I do something ( touch the screen, etc), the elements reset their positions to their first position.
I found this: [blog]: [Animation Blocks resets to original position after updating text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25773952/animation-blocks-resets-to-original-position-after-updating-text) 
they say it's because elements have constraints or auto layout so turn it off  to fix it but I don't want to turn it off. 
Can we update constraints programmatically? 
is there an other solution?

here's my animation:

```
@IBOutlet var tfUser: UITextfiled!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
tfUser.center.x += view.bounds.width
}


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

     UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 1.8, options: [.CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
        self.tfUser.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
        //self.tfUser.frame = CGRectMake(0, 233, 375 , 89)
       // i tried CGRectMake but it delete the animation
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: use translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of UIView. like this `self.tfUser.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;`

Comment: thank you very much, it work !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comment of my question , @Hardik Shekhat told to use :

```
self.tfUser.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

it works for me !